# ERROR 1370 (42000) at line 5: execute command denied to user '@'localhost' for routine 'datepart'

Tags: sql, mysql

i have been trying to write a sql query for a problem statement and i have been facing this error

> ERROR 1370 (42000) at line 5: execute command denied to user
> '@'localhost' for routine 'datepart'

i tried this

```
WITH hours_worked as (
  

    SELECT
          emp_id,
             CASE 
           WHEN datepart(minute,TIMESTAMP) >= datepart(minute,lag(TIMESTAMP) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(TIMESTAMP AS date),emp_id ORDER BY TIMESTAMP)) then datepart(hour,timestamp) - datepart(hour,lag(TIMESTAMP) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(TIMESTAMP AS date),emp_id ORDER BY TIMESTAMP)) 
             ELSE datepart(hour,timestamp) - datepart(hour,lag(TIMESTAMP) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(TIMESTAMP AS date),emp_id ORDER BY TIMESTAMP)) - 1
           END AS hours_worked
    FROM   attendance
    -- only weekends
    WHERE  datepart(weekday,TIMESTAMP) IN(7,1)
    )
    SELECT
       emp_id,
          SUM(hours_worked) as hours_worked
    FROM  hours_worked
    GROUP BY emp_id
    ORDER BY hours_worked desc
```

Answer (score 0):

DATEPART() is not built-in function in MySQL. Hence this is user-defined function. See for this function definition and your current user grants/privileges.

Recommended solution: use [EXTRACT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) instead.